Reuse old kindle display
Is it possible to reuse the e-ink display of some kindle models with the raspberry pi?
I want to buy an used kindle from eBay, dismount the screen and use it with my raspberry pi. Are there HATs or adapters out there which can drive the display directly from the raspberry?
When looking for similar projects usually the kindle as a whole was used..

Saw some stuff a few years ago. You really should try your search engine first... we're not here to do your research for you.

e-ink displays are used to lower energy cost. Usually on battery operated devices. RPi's have a high energy cost. Even the Zero.

EPDiy is a driver board for affordable e-Paper (or E-ink) displays.
https://github.com/vroland/epdiy
They have example code on how to use it.
The second way is to jailbreak the kindle and control it via SSH, example https://blog.lidskialf.net/2021/02/08/turning-an-old-kindle-into-a-eink-development-platform/
And the third way is already mentioned in another answer, as a web browser.

I don't know if that is possible but one way of using a kindle as a basic interface is to use a Web page. Use Apache web server on the pi to publish a local network page and interact with that.
